# NSData to UIImage Conversion is not working?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, base64, nsdata

My server is giving me my jpg image in the following NSData format:

```
/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAASABIAAD/4QBMRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgAAgESAAMAAAABAAEAAIdpAAQA
AAABAAAAJgAAAAAAAqACAAQAAAABAAAGqKADAAQAAAABAAAI4AAAAAD/7QA4UGhvdG9zaG9wIDMu
MAA4QklNBAQAAAAAAAA4QklNBCUAAAAAABDUHYzZjwCyBOmACZjs+EJ+/8AAEQgI4AaoAwERAAIR
AQMRAf/EAB8AAAEFAQEBAQEBAAAAAAAAAAABAgMEBQYHCAkKC//EALUQAAIBAwMCBAMFBQQEAAAB
fQECAwAEEQUSITFBBhNRYQcicRQygZGhCCNCscEVUtHwJDNicoIJChYXGBkaJSYnKCkqNDU2Nzg5/
```

I am saving it to a file, and while reading that file, the img object in my code below is giving me nil, although imgData object is holding the saved data.

```
- (void)selectedAttachedFiledownloadedSuccessfully
{
    NSLog(@"\nFile has downloaded\n");
    NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[self pathOfTheImage]];
    NSString * imageExt = [self contentTypeForImageData:imgData];
    UIImage *img    = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
    self.imgView.image = img;
}
```

Checking NSData for the image formats, it's not matching any and my code below is returning me nil

```
- (NSString *)contentTypeForImageData:(NSData *)data {
    uint8_t c;
    [data getBytes:&c length:1];

    switch (c) {
        case 0xFF:
            return @"image/jpeg";
        case 0x89:
            return @"image/png";
        case 0x47:
            return @"image/gif";
        case 0x49:
        case 0x4D:
            return @"image/tiff";
    }
    return nil;
}
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong over here. Can any one guide me through this plz?

Answer (score 0):

You might have used the wrong encoding (such as `NSUTF8StringEncoding`) when storing the data.

`NSUTF32StringEncoding` should be used for image data.

Answer (score 0):

The NSData which you are getting back from server might be corrupted. If the data is not in proper format it will not give you back the proper image
Use `+ (instancetype)dataWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path options:(NSDataReadingOptions)mask error:(NSError * _Nullable *)errorPtr` to read your image back from file and check the value of `errorPtr`
Refer this link for explanation for the above method https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSData/dataWithContentsOfFile:options:error:

Answer (score 0):

The server was sending my the image in base64Binary string format. I changed it to NSData as:

```
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:output[1] options:NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters];
```

I save this data to my image file as:

```
 [data  writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

Read it to show it on image view as:

```
- (void)showImage
{
    NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[self pathOfTheImage]];
    UIImage *img    = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
    self.imgView.image = img;
}
```

It's working fine now.